# How to make Parent window unrelative to child dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am opening window using window.open on button click from CRM ribbon and from that window we are opening a new dialog window using openStdDlg .

So my question which I have is will it be possible to have that child dialog open when that parent window is closed because we have this issue from quite sometime like when I close the parent window the child dialog also gets closed automatically .

Can we make these 2 windows independent ??

Will that be possible ?

Comment: What you need is modeless dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **alwaysRaised=yes** option? Check if this works for you:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenModeless () {
            if (window.showModelessDialog) {        // Internet Explorer
                showModelessDialog ("modeless.htm", window, "dialogWidth:300px; dialogHeight:200px;");
            } 
            else {
                window.open ("modeless.htm", "","width=300, height=200, alwaysRaised=yes");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    First open a modeless dialog with this button:
    <button id="modeless_button" onclick="OpenModeless ();">Open a modeless dialog!</button>
</body>
```